# Changing Connection String to SQL Server Express has no effect

Tags: sql-server

Initially, my project (running on localhost with SQL Server Express) had a connection string to the database Test1:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestContext" 
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=Test1; User Instance=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Now, I want the same project uses a different database: Test2.
So I've changed the "Initial Catalog" in the connection string to Test2.
But, to my surprise, when I execute the application, the Test1 database is still the one to be used.
What am I doing wrong?
I've already try to stop/start the IIS and delete the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder with no success.

Comment: When you say `the Test1 database is still the one to be used`, what do you mean? Do you, for example, execute stored procedures like `Test1.dbo.usp_myProc` or select from tables like `Test1.dbo.myTable`?

Comment: You made me see the light ZLK. When I was trying to answer your question, I realized that the base of my Context was still "Test1": public TestContext() : base("Teste1") { } Just changed it to the new db name and it works fine. Thanks